# Shopware 6 Unable to find a matching sales channel for the request

Tags: dns, mapping, shopware6, valet

I have been stuck on this for long enough now, basically I am wanting to try and use Shopware 6 as a PWA.

To install shopware I make use of **Valet** and  **Git**.

But I am never able to use install Shopware6 in the right way because **I am always getting the same error:**

[image: Shopware error]

**This is how I am installing Shopware6:**

1. clone git repo -->https://github.com/shopware/production;
2. cd /production;
   -composer install (to install dependencies)
3. ./bin/console system:setup - At this step I am asked to input some datas:
4. Application environment [dev]:                    //dev;

   - URL to your /public folder [http://localhost]:    // http://production.test;
   - Blue Green Deployment (yes/no) [yes]:             //yes
   - Database user [app]:                              //root
   - Database password:                                //root
   - Database host [localhost]:                        //
   - Database port [3306]:                             //
   - Database name [shopware]:                         //
   - Database SSL CA Path []:                          //
   - Database SSL Cert Path []:                         //
   - Database SSL Key Path []:                          //

- Skip verification of the database server's SSL certificate? (yes/no) [no]:   //no

Once Shopware 6 is installed I would visit **production/public** to **create a valet link** (virtual host).

```
valet link production.test
```

I visit my virtual host on http://production.test

At this moment I always get the above mentioned error: **Unable to find a matching sales channel for the request: [http://production.test/"](http://production.test/%22). Please make sure the domain mapping is correct.**

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit odd. Good news is that your installation seems to be working, but for some reason it sounds like your SalesChannel -> domain is not set. Try logging into http://production.test/admin & going to the Storefront sales channel. There you can configure the domain.
You can see it here as an example:
[image]

Comment: Also make sure that the sales channel is really set to http:// ... not to https:// which will also not match.

Comment: @Alex My shopware has port 8080 when I go to `http://localhost:8080/admin#/sw/dashboard/index`. I am using these commands to install and activate the plugin `  docker cp $PLUGIN_NAME $SHOPWARE_CONTAINER_ID:/var/www/html/custom/plugins/
  docker exec -it $SHOPWARE_CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash -c "cd /var/www/html && bin/console plugin:install --activate $PLUGIN_NAME"``. By default, the domain URL of the storefront is `http://localhost/`. How can I set the domain URL of storefront from `http://localhost/` to `http://localhost:8080/` with a command?

Answer (score 1):

Was facing issue with the 6.5 branch.

Executed below commands.

```
php bin/shopware sales-channel:list
php bin/shopware sales-channel:create:storefront --url http://production.test
```

No trailing slash on URL param